# composer install pass command line argument or parameter to bin/console

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to make my symfony 3.0 app capable to work with multiple kernel.
real aim : Multiple applications in one project

Generally everything is OK. I edited bin/console it's content exactly as the following. It works exactly and results what I need via `php bin/console --app=api`
But when I execute `composer install` `bin/console` throws the Exception naturally it doesn't knows about `--app` parameter. I want to make something like `composer install --app=api` and desired behaviour it would pass the parameter to `bin/console` I checked documentation and almost every pixel of the internet couldn't find a solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// if you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
//umask(0000);

set_time_limit(0);

/**
 * @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../apps/autoload.php';

$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = $input->getParameterOption(array('--env', '-e'), getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');
$app = $input->getParameterOption(array('--app', '-a'));
$debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') !== '0' && !$input->hasParameterOption(array('--no-debug', '')) && $env !== 'prod';

if ($debug) {
    Debug::enable();
}

switch ($app) {
    case 'api':
        $kernel = new ApiKernel($env, $debug);
        break;
    case 'frontend':
        $kernel = new FrontendKernel($env, $debug);
        break;
    default:
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("[--app|-a=<app>]  app: api|frontend");
        break;
}

$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->getDefinition()->addOptions([
    new InputOption('--app', '-a', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The application to operate in.'),
]);
$application->run($input);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `composer install --no-scripts` to prevent automatically running `app/console` after installation.

Or you can remove the the `bin/console` commands from the `scripts` section in your `composer.json` altogether, which probably makes more sense. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/composer.json#L33-L34

Or you can use environment variables instead of arguments.

Comment: woow, I missed no-script flag. I can put bin/console related scripts to capistrano. no big deal. Thank you @Ryan.

Comment: I put a wrapper for composer and called name multicomposer. I added `$app = $input->getParameterOption(array('--app', '-a'));` to `$app = $input->getParameterOption(array('--app', '-a'), getenv('SYMFONY_APP'));` and contents of multicomposer sh https://gist.github.com/feyyazesat/f8a2dbd0b3553b0ef6b4